# How to access (and change) variable within a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, object, variables, attributes

in the function itemgen(), the variable "a" calls its own helper function gen(), creating variable "mag" (an int). Variable "b" calls a helper function gone(), which on its own creates another variable, "myn" (an int).  If "myn" has a certain value (2), then the value of "mag" has to change to 0. I just need help on how to access the above values within the given variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My code is below:

```
def itemgen():
    a = gen()
    b = gone()
    if b.myn == 2:
        a.mag = 0
```

I tried searching for another example of this, as well as print statements (print(a.myn)), but it keeps saying that "b" is a string object and has no attribute "myn". How else would I access this information?

Comment: What are the `gen()` and `gone()` implementations? Are they functions? Classes?